# Difference in groupby method call?

Tags: python, pandas

Say there is a Dataframe `x` with columns `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Is there a substantial difference in terms of computational efficiency and actual behavior of `groupby` method between the following (?):

```
1. x.groupby(['a', 'b'])
2. x.groupby([x['a'], x['b]])
```

if I just want to get a Dataframe of columns `a` and `b`?

Comment: if you just want a dataframe of columns 'a' and 'b'  just use df[['a', b']].  Replace df for the name of your dataframe. also remeber to use the two brackets.

Comment: But what about the second option? How is #2 different?